# How to wrap text to match indentation

Tags: css

What is the best way to wrap text where the indentation is set by the word before it, so that any wrapped text will continue with the same indentation.  Like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNIvI.png

I made a JSfiddle to work with as well - http://jsfiddle.net/dangoodspeed/DbYFb/1/

```
.left { float:left; font-weight:bold; margin-right:.5em; }
```

I know I can do it with a table for each line, but there has to be a better way.

Comment: Asking for *best* way is an opinion poll. It’s not constructive especially when no criteria for goodness are specified. And you don’t explain what is wrong with the most obvious and most robust approach, a `table` element (which you had used, but the question does not contain any complete example of *any* attempt, still less what is wrong with them).

Answer (score 1):

if you float element, give them a width and add overflow:hidden to element aside in the flow, you get it :
http://jsfiddle.net/DbYFb/3/

```
.left {
    float:left;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin-right:.5em;
    width:5em;
}
.right {overflow:hidden;}
```

see http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/ for more about floatting elements :)

Comment: That puts too much space between "Name" and "John Doe".  I wanted to keep it at .5em.

Comment: give yourself the width you like in css (or none http://jsfiddle.net/DbYFb/25/ ) :) , what will be usefull is that you understand how to deal , clear and wrap floatting elements :)

Comment: I think this is what the OP wants http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/DbYFb/26/ (remove the width:5em rule)

Answer (score 1):

This seems to produce exactly the effect you need, according to your screenshot. You said you didn't want tables. Those aren't exactly tables, just divs that behave like table cells :)

http://jsfiddle.net/DbYFb/18/

Rows are wrapped in a div that behaves normally, while both columns are given display: table-cell to get the effect you want. Whether this is a better way than using an actual table is up to you.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="left">Name:</div>
    <div class="right">John Doe</div>
</div>

.row div {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I actually had a table-cell solution, though yours is better.  A bit more succinct.  I was hoping there would be a nice way to do it with floats and inlines.  If all else fails, I'll probably use your method.  Thanks.